# SQL Wildcards using %%%

Tags: sql, wildcard

I'm wondering what problems I may not foresee by using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tanswer 
WHERE CourseID LIKE '%%%' AND Q39 LIKE 'p' AND Q42 LIKE 'a' AND Q43 LIKE 'a'
```

In particular using '%%%'.

The reason being, I have a dropdown that would send a '%' and in the sql I enclose it with the other two % to search through a set of courses, this query leaving the courseID searching through all courses.

The recordset returned seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if there's anything I may not be seeing by using three %%% together.  Is this a special use of wildcards that I've stumbled across?

Comment: Why is the dropdown sending `%`? Is that for an `All` option?

Comment: Hey buddy. did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 3):

These are equivalent:

```
 CourseID LIKE '%%%'
 CourseID LIKE '%%'
 CourseID LIKE '%'
```

Which is why your query behaves as you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ! to escape the inner `%`: i.e. `%!%%`

see [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

Comment: They are not trying to match a `%` symbol.

Comment: Actually that is my assumption. The question could be clearer. Agreed.

Comment: The reason I'm sending a % is because if I send nothing I get no recordset.  Which I find strange because in effect my query would be like this surely SELECT * 
FROM tanswer 
WHERE CourseID LIKE '%".$c."%' AND Q39 LIKE 'p' AND Q42 LIKE 'a' AND Q43 LIKE 'a'

Comment: where $c is what I'm sending.  If I send nothing I must only have two %%, odd!

Comment: Yes exactly - that's what must be happening - so I guess you get "everything"? Or you are just using foresight to pre-empt issues?